# Bring Syntax Highlighting to code blocks here on P.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code

We have a lot of code here. I think everyone agree that we need syntax highlighting.

EDIT:
[Support this feature request on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72797/enable-syntax-highlighting-to-code-blocks-on-programmers-se)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there should be syntax highlighting for any code-related posts...

I'll use the rest of this answer as a CW sandbox... (Haven't fount the meta.SO counterpart yet)
Feel free to improve examples with more syntax, add other languages or correct mistakes, etc.

<s>Testing code removed, syntax highlighting does not work on meta.</s>

Comment: you successfully argue against your own answer here, these length code snippets are easily readable. anything longer probably means the question actually belongs somewhere else. code highlighting would promote more noise here that should be on so or codereview.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: This meta question is [meta-tag:status-completed], see this [example post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/156723/666).

Comment: that isn't my point, my point is I don't think your arguments were successful, and I disagree as well, the stackexchange guys take away just as quickly as they give so you never know. :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: This question has gained enough upvotes, so the opposite will probably not happen. Furthermore, these were not arguments. I think you need to read my answer again, but that would be a waste of time if you're planning on getting the opposite to happen...

Answer (score -2):

No, simply because we aren't here for fixing code. There aren't that many examples of code being used, with most questions being text.

Comment: I agree, but I think we will have much more code. Are there any problem if implement this feature here? SO has a syntax highlighter, not an advanced one, but it has, I think SE team could bring to us easily otherwise I agree to leave this feature out.

Comment: Syntax highlighting for code blocks is already implemented and heavily in use on SO.  "Implementation" should be as simple as changing a single config variable.

Comment: @bigown @Roger Sorry, I completely forgot.

Comment: This is a programmer area, and sometimes, code is the best way to express something related to, hum, code. I voted this up.